# angular directive with attributes linked to function outside the parent scope

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular directive (restrict to an element), its have an attribute to link to a function (using "&" attribute)

for example:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myonclick: "&",
        },
        controller: 'myController',
        template: '<button ng-click="clicked()">Click me!</button>'
    }
});
```

i'm assigning a function to the attribute like this:

```
<my-directive myonclick="inScopeFunction()"></my-directive>
```

its work fine if the function is inside the angular controller scope.
but i cant assign it to a function outside the angular scope.

there is a working example at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0btE6f?p=preview)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since inScopeFunction() is a global method, you can call it directly inside your directive. Register a click listener on the element inside directive and call inScopeFunction() in listener callback. Here is the updated [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/aCjMZ2QouLalRELPphwQ?p=preview)

```
link: function postLink (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function () {
        window[attrs.myonclick]()
      });
    }
```

html:

```
<my-directive myonclick="outScopeFunction"></my-directive>
```

Comment: Yes, but i don't know the function inside the directive, and i want to get it an an attribute, to enable binding it each time to a different function

Comment: I have updated the plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/aCjMZ2QouLalRELPphwQ?p=preview. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller will have access to global objects so you can access it from there

```
  $scope.inScopeFunction = outScopeFunction
```

To access it from your directive controller you could pass in a string and call the global object from there

```
<my-directive myonclick="'outScopeFunction'"></my-directive>
...
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.clicked = function(){
    window[$scope.myonclick()]()
    }
});
```

Comment: Its true, but i need the directive to call the function directly. Thanks any way